# Make JavaScript Random Quote Generator Only Generate One Quote Per Day

Tags: javascript, angular, date, typescript, random

I have created a random quote generator for my Angular app. The component code looks like this:

```
qotd = this.quotes[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.quotes.length)];
```

That's pulling from data that looks like this:

```
  quotes = [
    {
      quote: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus euismod magna magna, euismod tincidunt libero dignis.",
      author: 'Sorato Violasa'
    },
    {
      quote: "Nullam dignissim accumsan magna vitae rhoncus. Phasellus euismod magna magna, euismod tincidunt libero dignis.",
      author: 'Vito Dignaora'
    },
    {
      quote: "In tincidunt imperdiet augue, quis sollicitudin mi tincidunt ut.",
      author: 'Hivalo Amettioa'
    },
    {
      quote: "hasellus accumsan erat vitae enim blandit, quis euismod ipsum sollicitudin.",
      author: 'Grasha Plojiva'
    },
  ];
```

And then in my view I do this:

```
<div class="quotes">
    <p class="quote">
        {{qotd.quote}} <br><br>
        ~ {{qotd.author}}
    </p>
</div>
```

The thing is, right now this will generate a new quote every time the component re-loads, which can be multiple times within a single session. What I realize now would be better is to make this a daily quote generator. So it would only generate a new quote if the date changes. What's the simplest way to implement something like this? It's easy enough to generate the date and day of the week, like this:

```
  date = new Date();
  dayNumber = this.date.getDay();
```

But how would I compute when the day of the week changes in order to fire off a new instance?

Comment: Why are you doing this on the client? Just do it on the server, once per day.

Comment: Fair point. That would work. But I'm still curious how one would do this on the client side. Say, for instance, when you were accessing an API that you could read from (for getting the quotes), but that's all.

Comment: maybe by using a PRNG and take the timestamp of today `Math.floor(Date.now() / 864e5)` the seed. therefore I can gereate a repeatable sequence of "random" numbers, like to shuffle this Array, or to fetch an index, ... or something simpler, like `index = (Date.now() / 864e5 ^ 0xa702fa) % array.length`

Comment: Math. random() is not random .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a scheme where the server prepares 3 quotes: one for yesterday, today and tomorrow. Each new day, yesterday is removed and a new tomorrow added. That way the quote on the client can be changed just after midnight client local time and everyone sees the same quote on their same local day.

Nowhere on Earth that is more than 14 hours different to UTC, so if server bases the keys on UTC every client will have a suitable number of quotes and the entire quote database isn't pushed to every client every time it changes.

```js
var quotes = {
  '20171012':{quote:'one',author:'fred'},
  '20171013':{quote:'two',author:'mary'},
  '20171014':{quote:'three',author:'sue'}
};

function showQuote(quotes) {
  var d = new Date();
  var key = '' + d.getFullYear() +
             ('0'+(d.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2) +
             ('0'+d.getDate()).slice(-2);
  return quotes[key]
}

// On 2017-10-13 shows quote: two, author: mary
console.log(showQuote(quotes));
```

Answer (score 0):

No... Wait ...
In case of you need to set specific quotes for each day, thats a different scenario of getting a random quote from a quote list, but having the same quote on eacb 24 hours, one day .
If you have one array, you ould probably use the rand function, and a count to get the total number of values of the array .
This ould return one value each time it loads .
So, there is another function called srand .
If you use srand, you Will set a seed .. and that seed is going to seed the srand .

ok /

So, the seed sets the srand result.. and the srand makes the randomization .
You can also try the shuffle fuction. IT also use a seed .

NoW, you need to find a value to use as seed, and you need that number changes in a 24 hours interval .

To use a interval, need a reference value. The server time and the user agent time may be used .

IF you use the seed '42', you hav the same result returned by the srand .

Check it out:
suposing that you have a 42 quotes list .
First create the array, sets the seed variable, get the value .

$numbers = range(1,42);
$seed = floor(time()/86400);
The value of seed is set by the server unix timestamp, its timezone independent (=UTC) .
As need one day interval, calculate by using the 86400 value, total seconds of one day .
Randomize array
shuffle($numbers);
and echo the first result .
Lets use 200 quotes lisst :

```
$quoteslist= range(1,200);
$seed = floor(time()/86400);
echo $seed;

$resultado = $quoteslist;
$seed = floor(time()/86400);
 shuffle($resultado);
echo $resultado[$i];
```

The value returned by time(), the timestamp, changed to 18846 thats the seed for today .

Than, shuffles the list using that value as seed .

Get the first result .

```
// you need find the array count. Lets create an array of a 200 quotes .
$quotes = range(1,200);
$seed = floor(time()/86400);
echo 'the seed is:'. $seed.' and that changes on next day .';
echo '<hr>';

// makes another range to use the same index
$quotes = range(1,200); 
$resultado = $quotes;

// first value of the array, no randomizing (its 1)
echo 'the first result of the range array : ';
echo $resultado[0];
echo '<hr>';

// lets echo the result of the shuffle, not using the srand and the seed, it prints each time one value .
$quotes = range(1,200); 
$resultado = $quotes;
shuffle($resultado);
echo 'first result of thhe array, shuffled.. but not using the seed:  ';
echo $resultado[0];
echo '<br> this changes each refresh';
echo " <hr> ";


// this prints a random number for each day, basing on using the seed 

$quotes = range(1,200);
$resultado = $quotes;
echo 'today: ';
$seed = floor(time()/86400);
srand($seed);
shuffle($resultado);
echo $resultado[0];
echo " * this changes everyday, same result for all reloads  <hr> ";

echo '<br>';
// this is the seed of today. using
$quotes = range(1,200);
$resultado = $quotes;
echo 'the day of seed 18846: first day - result never changes, because used specific seed : ';
srand(18846);
shuffle($resultado);
echo $resultado[0];
echo " <hr> ";

echo 'the result for 18847 seed , next day - never changes : ';
$quotes = range(1,200);
$resultado = $quotes;
// this is 2 days after
srand(18847);
shuffle($resultado);
echo $resultado[0];
```

Answer (score -1):

One approach you can take is saving the current day on the client via `localStorage`. In your component, check if we have the `currentDay` key in our localStorage, if not create it, save the `currentDay` value and the `qotd` inside of of an object.

The next time you reload your component, you should have a qotd assigned in your localStorage already so what we do is check the date saved in localstorage and the current one we generate. If they are different we know the day has changed.

```
  //PSUEDOCODE (haven't tested, but should give you a good idea)
  function(){
    this.qotd = this.quotes[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.quotes.length)];

    if(!window.localStorage.getItem('todayDate')){    
        let currentDay = new Date().getDay();
        let storageItem = JSON.stringify({
          currentDay,
          qotd: this.qotd
        })
        window.localStorage.setItem('currentDay',storageItem)
      } 
      else {
        var existingQOTD = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('todayDate'));
        let currentDay = new Date().getDay();
        if(existingQOTD.currentDay !== currentDay){
        let storageItem = JSON.stringify({
          currentDay,
          qotd: this.qotd
        })
          window.localStorage.setItem('currentDay', storageItem)
        }

      }
  }
```

Comment: While I like this approach, as is it doesn't actually work. Right now, with the above implementation, a new quote loads every time the component mounts, rather than just once a day. Currently working on a solution to this.

Comment: Localstorage? maybe you should focus onj changing the quotes, not checking if the day changed. in case of saving a date, each user Will see different quotes each day .. and Will not be quotes of  " the day " .. check out my sollution for it, using the unix timestamp to generate  a seed and feed the srand funcion.. its php... but yyou can do that same Way on javascript .